# Print unless field is equal to

Tags: arrays, perl, join

I have a list of data I would like to parse by field.

### Input:

```
asdlfj  sd;lfkjas   as;dlkfj    josh

ds;lakfjsd;lk           

asdlfj  sd;lfkjas   as;dlkfj    josh

safkl;j

sdlakfjsd;              

asdlfj  sd;lfkjas   as;dlkfj    josh

asdfl;kj            
1   sd;lfkjas   as;dlkfj    josh

2   sd;lfkjas   as;dlkfj    jim

3   sd;lfkjas   as;dlkfj    joe
```

### Code:

```
$my_names = qr/joe|jim|josh/
$my_numbers = qr/[0-9]/;

while (<>) {
    unless($F[3] eq $my_names && $F[0] == $my_numbers)
    {
        print;
    }
}
```

What I want to do is print unless each 4th field,[4], is equal to `$my_names` or unless each first field,[0], is equal to `$my_numbers`.

I'm not very sure how to create an array from the fields in my file.

I'm guessing it might have something to do with the "join" function but I'm not quite sure.  These fields are delimited by tabs by the way.

Comment: Use `=~`, not `==` or `eq`, to test a string against a regular expression.

Comment: Are you trying to use perl regexes?  You'll need to use the "matches" operator (`=~`) rather than comparison operators (`eq`, `==`).  split and join will probably be helpful here, yes.

Comment: Strongly suggest you use [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/) as a reference.  I make extensive use of it, as it is very detailed and helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You want [`split`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#split), which is the opposite of `join`.

```
while (<>) {
    my @F = split;   # with no arguments, means:  split /\s+/, $_
    ...
```